# Why does a kernel density estimate of a normally distributed vector have a non-smooth second derivative?

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing

I had some normally distributed data:

```
mu <- 3
sigma <- 5
x <- rnorm(1e5, mu, sigma)
```

I took a kernel density estimate with a fairly high bandwidth:

```
kernel_density_of_x <- density(x, bw = 5)
```

Then I differentiated it:

```
differentiate <- function(x, y)
{
  diffOfX <- diff(x)
  data.frame(
    x      = x[-length(x)] + (diffOfX / 2), 
    dyByDx = diff(y) / diffOfX
  )
}

first_derivative <- with(kernel_density_of_x, differentiate(x, y))
```

This looked just as expected:

```
library(ggplot2)
(p1 <- ggplot(first_derivative, aes(x, dyByDx)) + geom_line())
```

[image: the first derivative looks smooth, as expected]

When I differentiated again, I expected another smooth curve, but I saw an odd cyclical effect.

```
second_derivative <- with(first_derivative, differentiate(x, dyByDx))
(p2 <- p1 %+% second_derivative + ylab("d2yByDx2"))
```

[image: the second derivative is unexpectedly noisy]

I tried a few different options for the `kernel` argument, but the noisiness persisted.
Dropping the bandwidth down to, for example, `0.5` gave a lower frequency noise that dominated the plot (making it nonsense).

Dropping the number of sampling points down from `n = 512` to `n = 32` stopped the issue, but that causes other problems.

Why does this effect occur? Is it an artifact of the `density` function, or have I done something silly?

---

We can redraw the plot using the probability density function of the normal distribution that `x` was generated from to see the shape I expected:

```
xx <- seq.int(-20, 20, 0.1)
pdf_of_xx <- dnorm(xx, mu, sigma)
first_derivative_of_xx <- differentiate(xx, pdf_of_xx)
second_derivative_of_xx<- with(first_derivative_of_xx, differentiate(x, dyByDx))
ggplot(second_derivative_of_xx, aes(x, dyByDx)) + geom_line()
```

[image: the second derivative created directly from the probability density function is smooth]

Comment: The noise effect doesn't happen if you start with a synthetic probability density function created with `dnorm`.

Comment: It's an artifact due to approximations made by the underlying `R` code; the discrete second derivative operator greatly magnifies the small errors.  This has been discussed in another thread which I cannot at the moment find ...  When you think about it, smoothness of the derivative (of a kernel density estimate as computed in `R`) isn't even defined in this context, because everything in sight is a discrete set of points, anyway.

Comment: @whuber I clearly recall such a thread, but I can't find it either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) [commented](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96730/why-does-a-kernel-density-estimate-of-a-normally-distributed-vector-have-a-non-s#comment188519_96730), what you're seeing is due to the approximation (via a fast fourier transform) that `density` uses.

If you calculate the kernel density estimate by brute force and compare it to the estimate that `density` gives, you'll see this sort of cyclic pattern in the differences.

The 2nd differences in the result from `density` result in an exaggeration of the effect. The second differences from the brute-force kernel density estimate don't show that pattern, but the calculation is like 3 orders of magnitude slower.

I put some code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kbroman/213faf0a9033a439b722). My brute-force kernel density estimate is the following:

```
mydensity <-
function(dat, x, bw=5) # dat=the data; x=points to calculate density estimate
{
  y <- vapply(x, function(a) mean(dnorm(a, dat, bw)), 1)
  data.frame(x=x, y=y)
}
```

Here's a picture of the second differences, blue from `density` and red from brute-force approach.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your codes in the gist you used a hard-entered bandwidth (`bw=5`) which is very different from a optimal one returned for example as:

```
library(ks)
h <- hpi(x)
```

which is actually about `h=0.85`.

It is interesting to execute your codes where `bw` is set to `h`. Then the final figure is as below. Here the differences are not so drastic.  [image]