# FFT for speeding up kernel density estimation

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing

One of the method for speeding up Kernel Density Estimation calculations is based on using FFT. This is implemented for example in `kde{ks}` R function. But unfortunately, a serious problem exists while trying to use this `kde{ks}` for unconstrained (full) bandwidth matrices. Below I try to explain it.

First, load a sample dataset and set some inputs:

```
library(ks)
library(mvtnorm)
data(unicef)
x <- cbind(unicef[,1], unicef[,2])
# grid sizes
gs1 <- 40
gs2 <- 40
# for nlevels in contour
nl <- 16
par(mfrow = c(2,2), pty="s")
```

Now execute `kde` with `binned=F` and plot a contour.
`H` is the unconstrained bandwidth matrix. The density seems quite good (`Fig. 1`).

```
H <- Hpi(x)
fhat1 <- kde(x=x, H=H, supp=99, gridsize=c(gs1,gs2), xmin=c(min(x[,1]),min(x[,2])), xmax=c(max(x[,1]),max(x[,2])), binned=F)
contour(fhat1$eval.points[[1]], fhat1$eval.points[[2]], fhat1$estimate, main="H is unconstrained, binned=F", nlevels=nl, xlab="Fig. 1")
points(fhat1$x, fhat1$y, col='red')
```

Now I do the same, but now with `binned=T`.
I get an alert: *Binned estimation for non-diagonal bandwidth matrix H can be inaccurate.*
`fhat2$H` shows that the unconstrained bandwidth was used as an input. The density seems rather strange (`Fig. 2`).

```
fhat2 <- kde(x=x, H=H, supp=99, bgridsize=c(gs1,gs2), xmin=c(min(x[,1]),min(x[,2])), xmax=c(max(x[,1]),max(x[,2])), binned=T)
contour(fhat2$eval.points[[1]], fhat2$eval.points[[2]], fhat2$estimate, main="H is unconstrained, binned=T", nlevels=nl, xlab="Fig. 2")
```

Now I change manually `H` into a diagonal form and execute `kde` again.
`Fig. 3` is almost identical (or at least similar) to `Fig. 2`. This suggests that `kde` uses (internally) a form of the `diagonal H`, instead of the `unconstrained H`.

```
H <- Hpi.diag(x)
fhat3 <- kde(x=x, H=H, supp=99, bgridsize=c(gs1,gs2), xmin=c(min(x[,1]),min(x[,2])), xmax=c(max(x[,1]),max(x[,2])), binned=T)
contour(fhat3$eval.points[[1]], fhat3$eval.points[[2]], fhat3$estimate, main="H diagonal, binned=T", nlevels = 20, xlab="Fig. 3")
```

Now I become suspicious that turning on the binning makes some difficulties while using `kde`. After a short inspection of `ks` source codes I realized that FFT was used to speed up the calculations and this FFT procedure is not "ready" for supporting `unconstrained H` bandwidths.
Is it true? To check my suspicions I have create a simple code for calculating `fhat` WITH binning and WITHOUT using FFT (that is with radially symmetric kernels). Below is the code (not optimized for speed, literal implementation of the definition in fact):

```
bkde.no.fft.radial <-  function(x, bandwidth, gridsize) {
  range.x <- list(c(min(x[,1]),max(x[,1])),c(min(x[,2]),max(x[,2])))
  n <- nrow(x)
  M <- gridsize
  H <- bandwidth
  d <- ncol(x)

  a <- c(range.x[[1]][1], range.x[[2]][2])
  b <- c(range.x[[1]][3], range.x[[2]][4])

  binned <- binning(x=x, bgridsize=c(M), xmin=c(a[1],a[2]), xmax=c(b[1],b[2]))
  gcounts <- binned$counts
  gpoints1 <- binned$eval.points[[1]]
  gpoints2 <- binned$eval.points[[2]]

  temp <- 0
  row <- 0
  col <- 0
  result <- matrix(nrow=M[1], ncol=M[2])
  for(i1 in 1:M[1]) {
    row <- row + 1
    for(i2 in 1:M[2]) {
      # for observing the progress
      cat(i1, "/", M[1], "---", i2, "/", M[2], "\r")
      flush.console()
      col <- col + 1
      for(j1 in 1:M[1]) {
        for(j2 in 1:M[2]) {
          if (gcounts[j1,j2] != 0) {
            temp <- temp + dmvnorm(c(gpoints1[i1],gpoints2[i2]) - c(gpoints1[j1],gpoints2[j2]), sigma=H) * gcounts[j1,j2]
          }
        }
      }
      result[row, col] <- temp / n
      temp <- 0
    }
    col <- 0
  }
  list(x1=gpoints1, x2=gpoints2, estimate=result)
}
```

Execute the above function (works very slow):

```
H <- Hpi(x)
fhat4 <- bkde.no.fft.radial(x=x, bandwidth=H, gridsize=c(gs1,gs2))
contour(fhat4$x1, fhat4$x2, fhat4$estimate, main="H is unconstrained, binned=T, radially symetric kernels", nlevels = 20, xlab="Fig. 4")
```

It can be observed that `Fig. 1` is identical with `Fig. 4` and it proves that the `unconstrained H` was used correctly. This experiment shows that `kde` with `binned=T` and the unconstrained bandwidth H used **CAN NOT** make use of radially symmetric kernels if this is implemented with FFT!

And now my the most interesting and fascinating question:
**Is it possible to utilize FFT for implementing fast kde with the unconstrained bandwidth H support?**

Below I enclose the image generated after executing all the code fragments given above.
![figures][5]

The problem described above seems similar to the one given [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96730/why-does-a-kernel-density-estimate-of-a-normally-distributed-vector-have-a-non-s), as in both posts FFT-like-nature seems to be responsible for "noise effects".

[image]

Comment: IMO, this question belongs here. It would be useful if some of the people who voted to close it could explain why they see it as belonging to SO.

Answer (score 3):

Recently, the problem was successfully solved. Please, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02766 for details. Similar problem, relating the unconstrained bandwidth selection, was presented here https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07482